# Tic Tac Toe array wrong characters

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, character, tic-tac-toe

The screenshot says it all, the characters i use are correctly put inside the array. However, some other random characters are inserted in the array as well. I'm confused!

main.cpp :

```
#include "Players.h"
#include "GameLayout.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char gameBoard [3][3];
    cout << "**** Welcome to Leviathan's first TicTacToe Game! ****\n\n";
    Players playersObject;
    playersObject.getPlayersNames();
    playersObject.printPlayersNames();
    GameLayout gameObject;
    gameObject.printLayout();
    Game gamestartObject;
    gamestartObject.gameStart(gameBoard);
}
```

game.cpp :

```
#include "Players.h"
#include "GameLayout.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Game::gameStart(char board[3][3])
{
    char player1char,player2char;
    size_t i,j;
    cout << "Enter player 1 character :";
    cin >> player1char;
    cout << "Enter player 2 character :";
    cin >> player2char;
    int row,column;
    bool isDone = false;
    while(isDone == false)
    {
        cout << "Player 1->choose row";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Player 1->choose column";
        cin >> column;
        board[row-1][column-1] = player1char;
        cout << "Player 2->choose row";
        cin >> row;
        cout << "Player 2->choose column";
        cin >> column;
        board[row-1][column-1] = player2char;
        GameLayout layout;
        cout << "  |1||2||3|" <<endl;
        for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                cout << i+1 << "|";
                for(j=0; j<3; j++)
                {
                    cout <<" "<<board[i][j] << " " ;
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
    }
}
```

Players.cpp :

```
#include "Players.h"
#include "GameLayout.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void Players::getPlayersNames()
{
    string p1,p2;
    cout << "Enter player 1 name : ";
    cin >> p1;
    cout << "\nEnter player 2 name : ";
    cin >> p2;
    _player1Name = p1;
    _player2Name = p2;
}

void Players::printPlayersNames()
{
    cout << "Alright " << _player1Name << " and " << _player2Name <<", the game has begun!\n\n";
}
```

GameLayout.cpp :

```
#include "Players.h"
#include "GameLayout.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void GameLayout::printLayout()
{
    size_t i,j;
    char board[3][3];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    cout << "  |1||2||3|" <<endl;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "|";
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            cout <<" "<<board[i][j] << " " ;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Game.h :

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H


class Game
{
    public:
        void gameStart(char board[3][3]);
    private:
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

GameLayout :

```
#ifndef GAMELAYOUT_H
#define GAMELAYOUT_H


class GameLayout
{
    public:
        void printLayout();
    private:
};

#endif // GAMELAYOUT_H
```

Players.h :

```
#ifndef PLAYERS_H
#define PLAYERS_H
#include <string>


class Players
{
    public:
        void getPlayersNames();
        void printPlayersNames();
    private:
        std::string _player1Name;
        std::string _player2Name;
};

#endif // PLAYERS_H
```

Comment: Please debug it yourself then remove ALL your codes and put only a [MCVE] so it gets **clear** for readers _where_ and _what_ is the error

Comment: @FirstStep Sorry, i'll try and do that next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local non-static variables in a function, like e.g. `gameBoard`, are not initialized. You need to explicitly initialize it, or its contents will be *indeterminate* and reading its values will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You can simply do it like

```
char gameBoard [3][3] = { ' ' };
```